# Java spring SseEmitter/ResponseBodyEmitter: detect browser reloads

Tags: java, spring

I'm using server-side events (SSE) in Java Spring. Whenever a new client subscribes to the events service I execute the following code at the REST controller:

```
SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
        logger.debug(TAG + "Emitter completed.");
        emitters.remove(emitter);
    });
return emitter;
```

Then, whenever an event needs to be notified to the clients I execute:

```
 for (ResponseBodyEmitter emitter: emitters) {
        emitter.send("Message #1");
 }
```

The problem is that when one of the clients reloads the browser, the emitter does not get completed (as I expected), and I get a broken pipe exception when calling the code above. Only after this exception is triggered I see the emitter being completed.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the browser reloads, it will establish a new EventSource to your server, right? Your problem is with the old one, which has no client endpoint anymore.

I suggest you try to detect that it is the same client connecting, and then explicitly call complete on the old emitter.

In my case I can detect this based on a token which the EventSource passes in as a URL parameter. When I hook the newly created emitter to a "user object", I make sure to complete the previous emitter before assigning the new to the user field variable.

From your code, it seems you have a list or set of emitters. Can you maybe make it a map instead, where you have some client identity as the key, and the emitter as the value?

I can't tell you exactly what piece of information to use as a client identity, since it all depends on your application. In my case it is a JWT token, but you could perhaps simply create a client numbering scheme...

Comment: how are you handling multiple tabs, the jwt will be same for all tabs in the session, right?

Comment: what if the client closes the app abruptly, never come back for 30 days, The old connection will still stay open ? This also doesnt work well when there are multiple App servers loadbalanced - since the user could connect to a different AS when they reconnect. This doesnt seem like a promising approach.

Comment: No, the SseEmitter is created with a timeout value in the constructor. The timeout is not relative to being idle, but more like a "time-to-live". By design the connections will be dropped every e.g. X seconds/minutes, and the client will recreate it ... if it is still needed. Regarding load balancing, of course when the client connects or reconnects, the server code must not rely on state in memory to recreate the client's session. But again, the design of the SSE and also Spring's SseEmitter is inherently session/connection centric, so as long as the connection is alive, you can work in mem.

Comment: ... and when it times out, you will receive the timeout callback. (SseEmitter.onTimeout(...))